# How to display user defined (pretty) URLs

Tags: java, php, html, apache

I have created a text link on my Website.

1. when a user click on the link, it takes him to a the page: `www.example.com/toronto_streets.php`
   but, I want the URL to be displayed as `www.example.com/toronto.on/`
2. then when user selects one street from this page, the url will be
   `www.example.com/street_landing_page.php?street=Option`
   but, I want the URL to be displayed as `www.example.com/toronto.on/house-for-sale-option`

I tried with editing .htacccess file but that didnt work...

Here is what I added to the *.htaccess* file:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule  ^toronto.on/house-for-sale-condo-mls/?$   house-for-sale-condo-mls.php  [NC]  #...
```

So will the above line Redirect `www.example.com/toronto.on/house-for-sale-condo-mls/` to `www.example.com/house-for-sale-condo-mls.php`?

when Im calling the URL, `www.example.com/toronto.on/house-for-sale-condo-mls/` ,  Im getting this error :

> The requested URL /toronto.on/house-for-sale-condo-mls was not found
>   on this server.

---

Update:

This is my current .htaccess file. It Redirects `www.example.com/toronto.on` to a page called `cate.php` with the city value= 'toronto' and province='on'.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine on 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ example.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

Comment: You Need to do some Research about the Apache Extension `mod_rewrite` That allwos you do stuff like that; What did you try to write into your .htaccess?

Comment: and need to have your "friendly" urls embedded in any html you sent to the client. no amount of mod_rewrite mangling can possibly fix a url in the client's browser if the html you send out contains the internal "ugly" urls.

Comment: i have edited the question to reflect what i did with .htaccess file

Comment: thnak you @j_s_stack .so is the .htaccess the only way? is there any other method in php that acan achieve this ?

Comment: Not really, you can do one, but that Needs more ressources and time for maintanece etc. so not really recomended

Comment: thank you @j_s_stack. My website recognises www.example.com/toronto.ontario/mls-real-estate-for-sale/ ..the fact that it is recognised proves thet there is some mechanism right? but i dont see any rewrite rule in the .htaccess file..how is this possible ?

Comment: Can you update your Question with the current .htaccess File?

Answer (score 0):

In the .htaccess, you would use a set of rewrite rules, such as the following:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^toronto.on(/*)$ /toronto_streets.php [L]
RewriteRule ^toronto.on/house-for-sale-option /street_landing_page.php?street=option [L]
```

You can use this site to help you test the rewrite rules: [click here](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/)

However, as others have pointed out, what appears in the URL bar will be what a href that is requested by the page. Thus the links on the page html should be modified to user the friendly URLs (e.g. /toronto.on/house-for-sale-option, rather than the backend url /street_landing_page.php?street=option

Comment: thank you @Nick Vasic  i edited my .htaccess and still getting error 404 . is there something i am missing?

Answer (score 0):

1) There are 2 mistakes in the Rewrite Rule you stated in your Question:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/house-for-sale-condo-mls.php?$ /toronto/house-for-sale-condo-mls/ [QSA,NC,L]
```

One is in your head: **You need to have your "friendly" urls embedded in any html you sent to the client. ** The .htaccess doesn't make bad to pretty URLS it makes pretty URLS internaly redirecting to the real site.
That means that your Links on the site need to contain:

```
<a href="/house-for-sale-condo-mls.php">The Text</a>
```

The seccond one was a missing Backslash.

The same for Point 1 of your Question:

```
RewriteRule ^/toronto.on /toronto_streets.php [QSA,NC,L]
```

Ist probably a good Idea to put another Rewrite Rule like this in front of the Top ones:

```
 RewriteRule ^/toronto_streets.php /toronto.on  [R=301,L]
```

If somethere the Link isn't Change (an external ressource) it Redirects the user to the pretty URL.

Comment: this is my current .htaccess file. it redirects "www.example.com/toronto.on" to a page called cate.php with the city value= 'toronto' and province='on'.  Options +FollowSymLinks
 RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]